# Angular directive for a highlighted word anywhere in website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm new to angular and i need some interesting functionality. When i highlight (double click) a word in some paragraph i need to be given a drop down menu where I can save that word, translate that word and other options. I couldn't find any solutions for this functionality.

Comment: I'm not too sure a directive is the way to go here. You probably want to use a service that registers a (double-) click handler on the body, and continue from there.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.